# Writing to a spreadsheet with Python 2.65

Tags: spreadsheet, python-2.6, xlwt

I am trying to make some Python 3.6 code work in a Python 2.65 environment. I've made most of the corrections but I cannot import module `xlwt`. It imports `xlrd` just fine. I tried `openpyxl` but that was not available either. Does Python 2.65 come with any standard module that will write to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Please explain why this is considered off topic. If necessary, I will withdraw the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standard module to communicate with Excel or any spreadsheet app. The only standard module is `csv`. The rest is 3rd party.